# Ipython Magic - Cant get it to install Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: python, ipython

I have followed the instructions here clearly https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/install.html#dependencies

Ran these commands below.

```
pip3 install ipython
pip3 show ipython
pip3 install pexpect jedi pygments setuptools decorator prompt-toolkit pickleshare backcall traitlets
```

I still get this error

```
>>> %precision 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    %precision 2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you ran that code inside the same python shell you used to install IPython.

I think you should open the IPython shell by invoking `ipython` from a terminal and run the code from there.